# как правильно конвертировать str на list

Tags: python, list, строки

```
for i in range(3):
    v = input('Enter the value: ')
    v = list(v)
    print(v)
```

Comment: а метод split вам не подойдёт ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью генератора списка:

```
v = [input('Enter the value: ') for _ in range(3)]
```

Или просто циклом и методом добавления в список `append`:

```
v = []
for _ in range(3):
    text = input()
    v.append(text)
```

Comment: Объяление именованных переменных без их использования в python не приветствуется. В описанных Вами случаях было бы корректней использовать `_` вместо `i`